# Why can't I get a device token from the simulator in swift5?

Tags: ios, swift, token, device

I am developing iOS with swift. My problem is that I can't get a device token value from the simulator. Is this normal? I have to do a push test. Is push testing possible only on the physical device?

**AppDelegate**

```swift
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        //create the notificationCenter
       let center  = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
       center.delegate = self
        // set the type as sound or badge
       center.requestAuthorization(options: [.sound,.alert,.badge]) { (granted, error) in
            // Enable or disable features based on authorization
        }
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        return true
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        let token = deviceToken.map{ String(format: "%02x", $0) }.joined()
        Log.Info("Registration succeeded!")
        Log.Info("Token: \(token)")
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        Log.Warning("Registration failed!")
    }
```

Comment: Is this norma? -> `YES`
Is push testing possible only on the physical device -> `YES`

Comment: But you can test local notifications in simulator.

Comment: APNS is only possible on an actual device. you can't test on simulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @SPatel said, it could only be tested on a real device. I hope it will improve in the future

Comment: Probably not. The design of the notification service probably won't allow that.

Comment: @Sulthan It seems difficult to test because it is limited to a real device.

Answer (score 3):

First of all you can't test push notification on simulator. For testing push notification you required physical device.

Simulator not provide device token. only physical device provide device token in delegate method of notification.